# Watch folder and transcode videos

Tags: video, directory-structure, video-conversion, transcode

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders, each of which contains multiple file formats like FLV, F4V, WMV, MOV, AVI, M4A, VOB & MPG .
I want to convert all files to MP4 format and save the converted video in the destination path by automatically creating a sub folder(as like in the source path).

When i'm using media coder to convert,i am unable to access the sub folders.

Is there a tool that fits my requirement? I dont mind going for a paid tool.

Comment: Not a programming Q, see http://superuser.com

Comment: Thanks. I was out of luck after searching over net.